# How to reference a style defined in an Android module using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-xml

I've defined the following style in a module and I want to use it as a theme on an Activity

**Android Module's styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.Panel"></style>
</resources>
```

**Android application's AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:theme="@style/MyTheme"> ... </activity>
```

I'm using **IntelliJ**, and I get compilation error saying

> android-apt-compiler: AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: Error: No
>   resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
>   '@style/MyTheme').

How can I reference the style that is in the module's jar in my main application?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use module dependency instead of the jar dependency, your main app should depend on the library module that defines the style.

Comment: I want to distribute the JAR I created. Is it possible to use the resources defined in it?

Comment: Please [check this post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/). The main difference between the Android library and the jar library is that the latter cannot contain resources (such as styles).

Comment: Already read that page. I need the resources, so it's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library module's resources automatically get copied to and packed with App module, if module dependency is correctly set-up. That is: dependency on a module directory, not a jar file.

Library project's jar output does not package resources. Default android build tools don't support it.

There is special a packaging type called `apklib` used by `maven-android-plugin` that can package resources as well, but you have build with Maven to use this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I just fixed this issue, the project is like this:

- you have module (moduleLib, for instance)
- you have a module(moduleMain, for instance)
- moduleMain depends on moduleLib, and some themes of moduleLib are
  referenced in moduleMain

what I did:

1.set moduleLib as Library project

(menu->Project Structures...->Modules->moduleLib->facet Android -> check the "Is Library project"

2 set the moduleMain depends on the moduleLib

2.1 go to the setting of moduleMain(the steps are similar to the previous one)

2.2 switch to the "Dependencies"

2.3 click "+", and select "module Dependency" add the moduleLib

2.4 change the "scope" to Compile(I have tried to pick up the Provided, but I can't use the theme  then)

it works for me